# Why was this question locked?

Tags: discussion

[I feel that I have no control of my department](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/103415/i-feel-that-i-have-no-control-of-my-department)

I've seen far worse than this in here.  What gives?

Comment: See also: [What is a "locked" post? - When should a post be locked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228)

Comment: I locked it when a series of flags indicated that the OP was engaging in destructive edits and a rollback war with the community.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The OP was rolling it back and removing all content on a regular basis: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/103415/revisions

Comment: thx.  should I delete this q then?

Comment: I wouldn't. Accept the answer and move on. It's a good example of why questions can get locked. The only way I'd consider deleting it is if the original question is deleted and even then I don't know if I would.

Comment: I don't think "rolling it back" explains why it was a problem. The OP was repeatedly vandalizing their post; it was locked to stop them doing that.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes we will occasionally lock posts for either reason. Sometimes people get into "rollback wars" (where someone makes an edit and then it gets reverted/applied over and over again). I guess I use that phrase for both situations, I'll clarify in my answer here.